# iPhone:text of UIButton not getting 'nil'

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5

I am facing some strange issue in my app.

in my ViewDidLoad() method I set title of my button as follows.

```
[btnA setTitle:@"A" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

On another click event I want to set the value of this title as nil as follows.

```
[btnA setTitle:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

but when I print the log immediately after above statement as follows

```
NSLog(@"btnA:%@",btnA.titleLabel.text);
```

It prints the log as follows

```
btnA:A
```

and strangely when I run app in simulator the text of button shows me nothing so it becomes nil on click event.

What is the problem any guess?

Comment: I think you need to do `setTitle:@""` in place of `setTitle:nil`. As There cannot be a **nil** string but there can be an empty string. **nil** is basically for objects and not strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Following code

```
button.titleLabel.text   = @"";
```

or in your own code try with delay

```
- (IBAction)produceImage:(id)sender
{

     // Call another function which setthe title after delay

    [self performSelector:@selector(title:) withObject:sender afterDelay:2];

}

- (IBAction)title:(id)sender
{
   [sender setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

      NSLog(@"sender:%@",sender.titleLabel.text);


}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set title to empty string like this:

```
[btnA setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: It should work I have tested this. Try with new button maybe You have changed something. Write these three lines in `-ViewDidLoad` what's result with new button?

Comment: @ParthBhatt JustinBoo I have deleted my post, n i think now u both are much satisfied.

Comment: @Bhurudada: Yes it is not about being satisfied. It is because we should not have a habit of creating duplicate answers here.

Answer (score 1):

```
[btnA setTitle:@"" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

or set btnA = nil;

Answer (score -1):

you can do `setTitle @" " .`
setTitle @""`or`nil` is useless when you get the value from button again, It gives you the previous value